# Heat-Equation Separation Approach

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations

regarding solving the heat-equation $\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}-\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2}=0$ one obviously uses the separation approach $u(t,x)=X(t)\cdot Y(x)$. Then one finds a linear-combination of solutions. What if the approach is $u(t,x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty X_n(t)Y_n(x)$? (And I know that $Y_n$ are a basis of the hilbert space that the solution must be in).

I do have the Problem that if so I cannot explain why each part of 2 sums on each side of the "=" with Index n should be equal:

Using the approach in the equation leads to

$\sum_{n=1}^\infty X'_n(t)Y_n(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty X_n(t)Y''_n(x)$

Why is $X'_n(t)Y_n(x)=X_n(t)Y''_n(x)$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$? (which would lead to the same solutions as in the first possibility of an approach)

Thank you very much

Comment: I don't understand the question. Are you asking what if you assume that $u$ has this expansion but $X_n,Y_n$ aren't actually chosen so that the product $X_n Y_n$ satisfies the equation? You could do that but it doesn't help, so why would you do that?

Comment: its just that this is how this is supposed to do in a course i take... the approach consists of this linear combination because we know that this is the solution and then we just have to calculate all $X_n$ and $Y_n$.- so the question for me is (because i can do that), how i would explain that this approach also leads to the same solution

Comment: Well, without assuming something about the $X_n$ and $Y_n$, you could in principle get a different representation of the same solution. To argue that you have the same solution you need some theorem for uniqueness of the solution of the PDE with the given boundary conditions. Just writing down this expansion of the entire solution does not imply that the summands satisfy the equation.

Comment: I understand. This already answers my question - Thank you!

Comment: If i do know that $Y_n$ is a basis of the hilbert space where the solution u must be part of) - does that help then?

Comment: So what you would normally want for the heat equation is actually that the $Y_j$ are orthogonal, but even then that does not really help that much. What you really need is $X_i' Y_i-X_i Y_i''$ being orthogonal to each other, so that when $X_i' Y_i - X_i Y_i''$ is not identically zero, there is no way for the other summands to compensate. When $Y_i$ are eigenfunctions of the second derivative, this follows from $Y_i$ being orthogonal to each other, but otherwise it doesn't.

Comment: I see, so the proper way to do it is using the usual approach and then finding out that there exists a countable number of solutions? :)

Comment: There aren't actually a countable number of solutions, just a countable number of independent eigenfunctions from which you can construct uncountably many solutions. But yeah the proper way to do it is to expand in terms that are already known to be solutions and then exploit orthogonality to extract coefficients.

Comment: Thanks for the correction! I think i get it now. Thank you for your time! :)